# How to make number grid

Tags: grid

i want help with making a grid that have 10 rows across the screen and 20 down the screen using while and other loops. 
The number range is from 1 - 50 this is my process so far
i tried doing this and it will print numbers from 1 to 50 down ths screen

this is my process so far:

```
for (int num=1; num <=50; num++) {
            System.out.println(num);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    String retval= "";
    for (int num=1; num <=50; num++) {
        retval +=num+"|";
        if(num%10 == 0){
            System.out.println(retval);
            retval = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ! , what if i want it in reverse  is the only line will change is:  for (int num=50; num > 0 ; num--) {

Comment: Try it and see what happens

Comment: It shows only numbers till 10 , and doesn't show numbers less than 10 : 50|
49|48|47|46|45|44|43|42|41|40|
39|38|37|36|35|34|33|32|31|30|
29|28|27|26|25|24|23|22|21|20|
19|18|17|16|15|14|13|12|11|10|

Comment: Play with the function variables a little. It's pretty easy, I believe in you ;)